# Minimal API Service not injected using .NET Carter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, minimal-apis, carter

I´m creating an API in .NET using Carter. I have this Module Defined:

```
    public class VariationsModule : EntityModule<Variation>
    {
        public VariationsModule()
        {
            this.MainRoute = "api/variations";
        }

        public override Task AddEntity(HttpContext context, [FromBody] Variation entity, [FromServices] IEntityService<Variation> entityService)
        {
            return base.AddEntity(context, entity, entityService);
        }
}
```

Where `EntityModule` contains common methods to all the entities that I´m planning to add and is defined like:

```
public abstract class EntityModule<TEntity> : ModuleBase where TEntity : Entity
```

It also provides the basic endpoints for the modules:

```
public override void AddRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
{
    app.MapGet(this.MainRoute, this.GetEntities);
    app.MapPost(this.MainRoute, this.AddEntity);
    app.MapGet(this.MainRoute + "/{id:guid}", this.GetEntity);
    app.MapPut(this.MainRoute + "/{id:guid}", this.UpdateEntity);
    app.MapDelete(this.MainRoute + "/{id:guid}", this.DeleteEntity);
}
```

Module base is the implementation of the `ICarterModule` interface

The problem basically is that the `IEntityService<Variation>` in the `VariationsModule` is null so it's not correctly injected.

This is the definition of the `Variations Service`:

```
public class VariationsService : EntityService<Variation>, IVariationsService
```

`IVariationsService` inherits from `IEntityService<Variation>`:

```
public interface IVariationsService : IEntityService<Variation>
```

Where `EntityService<T>` is:

```
public abstract class EntityService<TEntity> : IEntityService<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
```

And then the Service is added in the DI Container like:

```
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IVariationsService, VariationsService>();
```

Am I missing something? First why do I need to specify `[FromServices]` in the Add method? Secondly how can I fix this problem? Might be an architectural problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`builder.Services.AddScoped<IVariationsService, VariationsService>();` will not register `IEntityService<Variation>` it will only register `IVariationsService`. One approach is to scrap `VariationsService` with interface completely and just register the open generic (if `EntityService` is not abstract and it's implementation is satisfactory):

```cs
 builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IEntityService<>), typeof(EntityService<>));
```

If you want specific registration then you will need to register it:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEntityService<Variation>, VariationsService>();
```

If you need it by both interfaces then:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IVariationsService, VariationsService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEntityService<Variation>>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<VariationsService>());
```